# Is there a better way to distinguish resizable containers than presence of allocator_type?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, containers, enable-if

I have template overloads for `operator>>()` where I need to distinguish between containers that can be resized, e.g., `vector`, and containers that cannot, e.g., `array`. I am currently just using the presence of an `allocator_type` trait (see code, below)--and it works just fine--but was wondering if there is a more explicit way of testing this.

```
template <class T>
struct is_resizable {
    typedef uint8_t yes;
    typedef uint16_t no;

    template <class U>
    static yes test(class U::allocator_type *);

    template <class U>
    static no test(...);

    static const bool value = sizeof test<T>(0) == sizeof yes;
};

template <typename C>
typename boost::enable_if_c<
    boost::spirit::traits::is_container<C>::value && is_resizable<C>::value,
    istream &
>::type
operator>>(istream &ibs, C &c)
{
    c.resize(ibs.repeat() == 0 ? c.size() : ibs.repeat());
    for (typename C::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it)
    {
        C::value_type v;
        ibs >> v;
        *it = v;
    }
    return ibs;
}

template <typename C>
typename boost::enable_if_c<
    boost::spirit::traits::is_container<C>::value && !is_resizable<C>::value,
    istream &
>::type
operator>>(istream &ibs, C &c)
{
    for (typename C::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it)
        ibs >> *it;
    return ibs;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from @Jarod42 on a separate question, I have a solution that works with C++98, C++03, and C++11; g++ and VS2015. Also, for the problem child, `std::vector<bool>`.

```
#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)                \
    template <typename U>                                                    \
    class traitsName                                                         \
    {                                                                        \
    private:                                                                 \
        typedef boost::uint8_t yes; typedef boost::uint16_t no;              \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                               \
        template<typename T> static yes check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);\
        template<typename T> static no check(...);                           \
    public:                                                                  \
        static const bool value = sizeof check<U>(0) == sizeof(yes);         \
    }

DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_resize_1, T::resize, void (T::*)(typename T::size_type));
DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_resize_2, T::resize, void (T::*)(typename T::size_type, \
    typename T::value_type));
```

This is how it's used, below. Notice that both the `has_resize_1` and `has_resize_2` member-function signatures for `resize()` are checked. That's because before C++11, `resize()` had a single signature with two parameters, the last with a default value; as of C++11, it has two signatures--one with one parameter and the other with two parameters. Moreover, VS2015 apparently has *three* signatures--all of the above. The solution is just to check for both signatures all the time.

There is probably a way to combine the two checks into a single type trait, such as `has_resize<C>::value`. Tell me if you know.

```
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<
    !boost::spirit::traits::is_container<T>::value,
    xstream &>::type
    operator>>(xstream &ibs, T &b)
{
    return ibs;
}

template <typename C>
typename boost::enable_if_c<
    boost::spirit::traits::is_container<C>::value &&
    (has_resize_1<C>::value || has_resize_2<C>::value),
    xstream &
>::type
operator>>(xstream &ibs, C &c)
{
    typename C::value_type v;
    ibs >> v;
    return ibs;
}

template <typename C>
typename boost::enable_if_c<
    boost::spirit::traits::is_container<C>::value &&
    !(has_resize_1<C>::value || has_resize_2<C>::value),
    xstream &
>::type
operator>>(xstream &ibs, C &c)
{
    typename C::value_type v;
    ibs >> v;
    return ibs;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test is a container is `resize`-able, you should probably just check to see if it has a `resize()` function. In C++03, that would look like:

```
template <typename T>
class has_resize
{
private:
    typedef char yes;
    struct no {
        char _[2];
    };

    template <typename U, U>
    class check
    { };

    template <typename C>
    static yes test(check<void (C::*)(size_t), &C::resize>*);

    template <typename C>
    static no test(...);

public:
    static const bool value = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes));
};
```

Comment: This is not gonna work; there's no guarantee that the signature of `resize` is in fact `void(size_t)`.

Comment: @Mehrdad, this is probably close enough for my needs.

Comment: @user4438540: I doubt it's sufficient... at the very least you want to check for `void(size_t, T)` too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to define/use a custom trait (like `boost::spirit::traits` are).

The presence or absense of an allocator doesn't really tell you whether a container is fixed-size. Non-standard containers might not have an `allocator_type` associated type at all, whilst still allowing `resize(...)`

In fact, since you're *effectively* asserting a *Concept* that allows

```
C::resize(size_t)
```

you could just use expression SFINAE for that

Answer (score 1):

Modern C++ has a really terse way :

```
template <typename T, typename = int>
struct resizable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct resizable <T, decltype((void) std::declval<T>().resize(1), 0)> : std::true_type {};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c3238c02de16b42)

Now if you don't need to disambiguate between member functions and member variables with the name `resize`, you could write the above `decltype` as follows :

```
decltype( (void) &T::resize, 0 )
```

<sup>note that the cast to `void` is done to handle cases where a type overloads the comma operator and generalizing fails (so it's just a better safe than sorry policy)</sup>

Comment: VS2015 complains about your solution with "error C2228: left of '.resize' must have class/struct/union" and "note: type is 'add_rvalue_reference<_Ty>::type'".

Comment: @user4438540 [1](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779916/decltype-and-declval-dont-work-as-expected) [2](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797682/c-decltype-of-class-member-access-incompletely-implemented)

Comment: Microsoft says in your second link that that "issue has been fixed: the fix will be included in a future release of Visual C++." VS2015 must be a "future release" because that bug doesn't show up, and the workaround is not needed. Therefore, I'm thinking that the C2228 issue I'm seeing is different.

Comment: I think [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1163010) is the same issue I'm having, and it appears to not be fixed yet in VS2015.

Comment: @user4438540 I was just mentioning the problematic legacy VS has with `declval`. The last issue you linked is spot on, though I believe VS had a problem with `void_t` as well (as W.Brown says when [presenting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0FliKwcwXE) `void_t` - that's where the snippet you mention is taken from, check @39.00).